# Execute SQL files that are in an S3 subdirectory

Tags: python

I am trying to execute multiple SQL files in an S3 subfolder and export them each to a CSV file within the same subfolder. When I run the code below I get the error: psycopg2.ProgrammingError: can't execute an empty query. Not sure why I am receiving this error.

This is what I have attempted so far.

```
import boto3
import psycopg2
import csv
import json
import os

def execute_sql():

    # S3 bucket and folder details
    S3_BUCKET_NAME = 'my-bucket'
    S3_SUBDIRECTORY = 'sql-files/'

    # Establish connection to Redshift
    secret_name = "my-secret"
    region_name = "us-east-2"
    session = boto3.session.Session()
    client = session.client(service_name='secretsmanager', region_name=region_name)
    response = client.get_secret_value(SecretId=secret_name)
    secret_data = response['SecretString']
    credentials = json.loads(secret_data)

    conn = psycopg2.connect(
        host=credentials['host'],
        port=credentials['port'],
        user=credentials['username'],
        password=credentials['password'],
        dbname=credentials['dbname']
    )

    # Initialize the S3 client
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')

    # List objects in the S3 bucket and folder
    response = s3.list_objects_v2(Bucket=S3_BUCKET_NAME, Prefix=S3_SUBDIRECTORY)

    # Iterate over SQL files in S3 folder
    for obj in response['Contents']:
        # Retrieve the SQL file name
        sql_file_name = obj['Key'].split('/')[-1]

        # Read the SQL file contents
        response = s3.get_object(Bucket=S3_BUCKET_NAME, Key=obj['Key'])
        sql_query = response['Body'].read().decode('utf-8')

        # Execute the SQL query against Redshift
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute(sql_query)

        # Retrieve the query results
        results = cursor.fetchall()

        # Convert the query results to CSV format
        csv_file_path = f'{sql_file_name}.csv'
        with open(csv_file_path, 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
            csv_writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
            csv_writer.writerows(results)

        print(f"Query results saved as CSV: {csv_file_path}")

    # Close the Redshift connection
    conn.close()

def main():
    execute_sql()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: The obvious explanation is that the files in the bucket really are empty.  Can you confirm some other way that they aren't empty?